# Incorrectly deleted W10 users - how to identify linked registry keys and delete them to repair conflict?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry

#### Problem

I want to find reliable way to fix situation where user folder (%homedrive%\Users<name>) was manually deleted without use of standard interface.

Without deletion of correct registry keys, I cannot restore profiles (not only damaged one) with my migration application*. It also forces user to login with temporary account instead of simply downloading new copy of profile from domain (which would allow to restore backup).

*I'm using USMT with Supergrate, it throws WMI errors).

Therefore I'm looking for all places which should be checked.
My target is to create PS script to automate repair for cases with many damaged accounts so if there is some dedicated option to delete remaining of accounts with Powershell without need to find all bits of information, I would be glad for pointing it out :)

#### Environment

I'm working with AD connected Windows 10 where domain users have local accounts on computers (Manual deletion is available in "Advanced system settings > Advanced > User Profiles > Settings").

#### Plausible keys

- Linked data surely lies in "HKU(SID)" and "HKU(SID)_Classes" (usually deleting this keys alone allows to repair profile)
- I'm pretty sure that I should delete also (SID) in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
- Should I also identify and delete keys in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileGuid" and "ProfileList" linked with SID in question?
- What about "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\hivelist"? Should I identify and delete values there? Is CurrentControlSet and ControlSet001 are only versions of this branches or should I prepare for other options?

#### Other linked keys

Below are all places I've found references to user account but I'm pretty sure that this values are irrelevant, as they are settings of specific applications or temporary/cached information and shouldn't break system. Are they?

- OpenDrive keys Paths of Installer MSIPC AppContainer\Storage MuiCache
- shell\open TypeLib Wow6432Node
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\DataStore\
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\ Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
- Security Health\State\Persist
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WlanSvc\MigrationData\Migration\WLANSVC\ProfileSync\PerUser\
- Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Printers\

Comment: have you tried to use the `.Delete()` method of the `Win32_UserProfile` CIM/WMI class?